# Change Read Only Functionality with a button in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

New to visual basic but I've been trying to learn it for Microsoft Access. In my database I have forms linked together for UI. The forms have an 'edit' button.

I want the form to not be editable until the 'edit' button is clicked. So I've made all attributes in the form to be read-only.

My button is not yet functional. I would like these 'read-only' attributes to be editable once the edit button is clicked.

I've tried this in the function for when the edit button is clicked:

```
Me.AllowEdits = True
TextFeild.Enabled = True
```

But it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are the fields locked? (i.e. TextField.Locked = true). I usually put a "Lock" toggle on my forms that alternates the "locked" property between true/false for all controls on the form.